# How to Wrap Content Inside div by div pure js

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<div id="a"><p>this is p</p></div>
```

I want to wrap content inside like

```
<div id="a"><div class="wrap"><p>this is p</p></div></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `wrap`?

Comment: Is [this](https://exceptionshub.com/pure-javascript-method-to-wrap-content-in-a-div-3.html) what you are asking?

Comment: Simply  ``document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = `<div class="wrap">${document.getElementById("a").innerHTML}</div>`;`` Suggest reading some basic tutorial about HTML DOM. Here is one for [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let curDiv = document.getElementById("a");
curDiv.innerHTML = `<div id="wrap">${curDiv.innerHTML}</div>`
```

```css
#a{
  border:1px solid green;
  padding: 6px;
}
#wrap{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="a">
    <p>this is p</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.outerHTML = `<div class="wrap">${p.outerHTML}</div>`;
```

```css
.wrap{border:2px solid blue}
#a{border:2px solid red}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <p>this is p</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var wrapDiv = document.createElement('div');
wrapDiv.setAttribute('class', 'wrap');

var children = document.getElementById('a').getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
children.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapDiv, children);
wrapDiv.appendChild(children);
```